# compare lists with while loop in python

Tags: python, while-loop

This code below is to make a list of the bigger number of the two lists in the same index positions.
How can I rewrite this code with a **while** loop instead of a **for** loop?

```
 a = [7,12,9,14,15,18,12]
 b = [9,14,8,3,15,17,15]
 big = []
 for i in range(len(a)):
     big.append(max(a[i],b[i]))
 print(big)
 [9, 14, 9, 14, 15, 18, 15]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pop()` in order to poop the first item of both lists each time till `a` or `b` evaluates as True (it's contain items):

```
In [15]: while a:
            big.append(max(a.pop(0),b.pop(0)))
   ....:     

In [16]: big
Out[16]: [9, 14, 9, 14, 15, 18, 15]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `zip` and `list comprehension`:

```
a = [7, 12, 9, 14, 15, 18, 12]
b = [9, 14, 8, 3, 15, 17, 15]
big = [max(t) for t in zip(a, b)]
```

Using `while`:

```
a = [7, 12, 9, 14, 15, 18, 12]
b = [9, 14, 8, 3, 15, 17, 15]

big = []
i = 0
while i < len(a):
    big.append(max(a[i], b[i]))
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is this with while

```
a = [7, 12, 9, 14, 15, 18, 12]
b = [9, 14, 8, 3, 15, 17, 15]
big = []
i = 0
while i < len(a):
    big.append(max(a[i], b[i]))
    i += 1
print big
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
a = [7,12,9,14,15,18,12]
b = [9,14,8,3,15,17,15]
big = []
i=0
while i<len(a):
    if a[i]<b[i]:
        big.append(b[i])
        i+=1
    else:
        big.append(a[i])
        i+=1
print(big)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try with `zip()` and list comprehension like so:

```
a = [7,12,9,14,15,18,12]
b = [9,14,8,3,15,17,15]
big = [max(c) for c in zip(a,b)]
print big
```

Output:

```
[9, 14, 9, 14, 15, 18, 15]
```